# AngularJS, TypeScript, Component Architecture [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have the following issue and don't know how to resolve it. 
Usually, I work in Angular 6 but get back for a while to AngularJS, and have some issues with DI I think.

I have the component architecture with typescript.

My appRootModule looks like this (w/o imports section)

```
export const appRootModule: IModule = module('testApp, ['asyncFilter'])
  .component('appRoot', new AppRootComponent())
  .component('postModal', new PostModalComponent())
  .service('componentsDataService', ComponentDataService);
```

And that's the service that gives the error.

appRootController:

```
export class AppRootController implements IController 
  private $http: IHttpService;
  private $cds: ComponentDataService;

  constructor($http: IHttpService, $cds: ComponentDataService) {
    this.$http = $http;
    this.$cds = $cds;
    /.../
  }

  public sendToModal(post: any): void {
    this.$cds.sendModalData(post);
  }
  public $onInit = async (): Promise<void> => {};
}
```

And the service file:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

export class ComponentDataService {
  private modalSubject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  public sendModalData(post: any): void {
    /.../
  }

  public clearModalData(): void {
    /.../
  }

  public getModalData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.modalSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Please help. I'm about to cry.

it gives me :

```
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cdsProvider <- $cds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When TypeScript transpiles your code to javascript it strips out the types and you end up with something like

```
var AppRootController = (function() { 
    function AppRootController($http, $cds) { /.../ } 
});
```

AngularJS can't find `$cds` and you get the error you're seeing. You need to use the name you have assigned to your service: `componentsDataService`. i.e.:

```
export class AppRootController implements IController 
  private $http: IHttpService;
  private $cds: ComponentDataService;

  constructor($http: IHttpService, componentsDataService: ComponentDataService) {
    this.$http = $http;
    this.$cds = componentsDataService;
    /.../
  }

  public sendToModal(post: any): void {
    this.$cds.sendModalData(post);
  }
  public $onInit = async (): Promise<void> => {};
}
```

Comment: That works differently in new Angular, and that's why I messed up. Thank you very much ;)